# Install org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:2.3.6.RELEASE on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud

I am working on a project and for compatibility reasons, I have to install 2.3.6.RELEASE of SpringBoot cli using sdkman. I have also installed maven using that. To enable the `encrypt` command of the `spring boot cloud`, I tried the below command.

`spring install org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:2.3.6.RELEASE`

and got the following error.

```
Resolving dependencies...
startup failed:
General error during conversion: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:jar:2.3.6.RELEASE in local (file:/home/iddi/.m2/repository/)

org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.DependencyResolutionFailedException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:jar:2.3.6.RELEASE in local (file:/home/iddi/.m2/repository/)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.grab(AetherGrapeEngine.java:116)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:166)
    at groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.visit(GrabAnnotationTransformation.java:376)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:358)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:965)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:642)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:618)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:595)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.GroovyCompiler.compile(GroovyCompiler.java:197)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.install.GroovyGrabDependencyResolver.resolve(GroovyGrabDependencyResolver.java:55)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.install.Installer.install(Installer.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.install.InstallCommand$InstallOptionHandler.run(InstallCommand.java:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.run(OptionHandler.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.OptionParsingCommand.run(OptionParsingCommand.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:219)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.runAndHandleErrors(CommandRunner.java:171)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.SpringCli.main(SpringCli.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:jar:2.3.6.RELEASE in local (file:/home/iddi/.m2/repository/)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:357)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:293)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:jar:2.3.6.RELEASE in local (file:/home/iddi/.m2/repository/)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:340)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:jar:2.3.6.RELEASE in local (file:/home/iddi/.m2/repository/)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401)
    ... 28 more

1 error
```

Can anyone help me to find out how to install it on Ubuntu 18.04?

I am currently using the Spring-cli installed from sdkman.

Comment: Hi, can you confirm if the `spring-cloud-cli.jar` file exists in your local repo `/home/iddi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-cli/2.3.6.RELEASE`?

Comment: No please. I am trying to download it using the spring cli.

Comment: So if you have a fresh machine and you follow the documentation https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-cli/reference/html/ it will not work. Trying to grab the meaning of the `mvn install` command in the doc which without a valid pom.xml will produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

add this artifact on your classpath

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-cli/2.3.6.RELEASE

(download jar), or if you are using maven add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-cli</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Apologies I should have mentioned I am using spring cli from sdkman for this.